# What are CFI directives in Gnu Assembler (GAS) used for?

Tags: assembly, callstack, gnu-assembler, stack-unwinding, debug-information

There seem to be a .CFI directive after every line and also there are wide varieties of these ex.,`.cfi_startproc` , `.cfi_endproc` etc..  [more here](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/CFI-directives.html#CFI-directives).

```
    .file   "temp.c"
    .text
.globl main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
.globl func
    .type   func, @function
func:
.LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
    movl    %esi, %eax
    movb    %al, -8(%rbp)
    leave
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1:
    .size   func, .-func
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.4.1-4ubuntu9) 4.4.1"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

I didn't get the purpose of these.

Comment: description of `cfi` instructions of `GNU AS` [here](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.24/as/CFI-directives.html#CFI-directives)

Comment: related: [How to remove “noise” from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output), if you just want the instructions without the directives.  On nice way is to put your code on http://gcc.godbolt.org/ to see nice filtered asm output from various versions of various compilers (including non-x86), with color highlighting to match source lines with asm blocks.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I've got a feeling it stands for [Call Frame Information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_frame#Structure) and is a GNU AS extension to manage call frames. From [DeveloperWorks](https://web.archive.org/web/20121010045618/http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/systems/library/es-gnutool/):

> On some architectures, exception
> handling must be managed with Call
> Frame Information directives. These
> directives are used in the assembly to
> direct exception handling. These
> directives are available on Linux on
> POWER, if, for any reason (portability
> of the code base, for example), the
> GCC generated exception handling
> information is not sufficient.

It looks like these are generated on some platforms depending on need for exception handling.

If you are looking to disable these, please see [David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16007194/257111).

Comment: Also can you say a word about .LFB0, .LFB1, .LFE0,  .LFE1

Comment: @claws - Those are compiler-generated labels (as you can see from the `:`). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/15285058/4294399

Answer (score 153):

To disable these, use the gcc option

```
-fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables
```

---

`-fno-dwarf2-cfi-asm` may be needed also.

Comment: `-fno-dwarf2-cfi-asm` may be needed also

Comment: If you're disabling it for human-readable asm output, see [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](//stackoverflow.com/q/38552116) for other useful options and tricks.

Comment: Interesting to note that the answer how to disable them got more upvotes than those which describe what are they :)

Answer (score 36):

The CFI directives are used for debugging. It allows the debugger to unwind a stack. For example: if procedure A calls procedure B which then calls a common procedure C. Procedure C fails. You now want to know who actually called C and then you may want to know who called B.

A debugger can unwind this stack by using the stack pointer (%rsp) and register %rbp, however it needs to know how to find them. That is where the CFI directives come in.

```
movq    %rsp, %rbp
.cfi_def_cfa_register 6
```

so the last line here tell it that the "Call frame address" is now in register 6 (%rbp)

Comment: But exception handling usage of cfi should be more frequent than debugging, I think.

Comment: Actually CFA stands for "canonical frame address". See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7535848/21475).

Comment: - [ImperialViolet - CFI directives in assembly files](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2017/01/18/cfi.html)

Comment: **CFI directives allow stack-unwinding even for code compiled with `-fomit-frame-pointer`, as an alternative to RBP** (which is on by default with gcc or clang `-O1` and higher).  It's used by C++ exception handling as well as debuggers / profilers.  In code *with* traditional RBP frame pointers, the current RBP value always points at a saved RBP value, and that points at the previous one forming a linked list.  There's no need for CFI in that case.  (Although in functions that use a frame pointer, CFI cfa_register avoids needing more metadata for every RSP change, like you're showing.)

Answer (score 4):

To disable these, g++ needs `-fno-exceptions` along with the previously mentioned `-fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables`, provided that you don't use exceptions.