# What is .cfi and .LFE in assembly code produced by GCC from c++ program?

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly

I have the following c++ code

```
int factorial(int n){

    if(n==0){
        return 1;
    }
    return n*factorial(n-1);

}

int main(void){
    factorial(5);
    return 0;
}
```

When I create an assembly file using g++ -S factorial.cpp I get the following:

```
    .file   "tail_call_opt.cpp"
    .text
.globl _Z9factoriali
    .type   _Z9factoriali, @function
_Z9factoriali:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    .cfi_personality 0x0,__gxx_personality_v0
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    subl    $24, %esp
    cmpl    $0, 8(%ebp)
    jne .L2
    movl    $1, %eax
    jmp .L3
.L2:
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax
    subl    $1, %eax
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    _Z9factoriali
    imull   8(%ebp), %eax
.L3:
    leave
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   _Z9factoriali, .-_Z9factoriali
.globl main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    .cfi_personality 0x0,__gxx_personality_v0
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    andl    $-16, %esp
    subl    $16, %esp
    movl    $5, (%esp)
    call    _Z9factoriali
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

I can follow most of this, but what is the purpose of the .cfi and the .LFE parts?
Where can I learn more about the assembly produced by gcc?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are CFI directives in Gnu Assembler (GAS) used for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529185/what-are-cfi-directives-in-gnu-assembler-gas-used-for)

Comment: It's not a dupe. The other question doesn't cover LFE.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

These directives tell gas to emit Dwarf Call Frame Information tags which are apparently used to reconstruct a stack backtrace when a frame pointer is missing. In your case the frame pointer is present, so I guess it could be used to perform unwinding during exception handling. Such mechanism has less overhead than the old sjlj (`setjump`/`longjump`) one. See [here](http://www.logix.cz/michal/devel/gas-cfi/), and also the linked Dwarf spec.

As for `.Lxx` labels, `.L` prefix indicates that the label is local to this file and so will not conflict with the same-name labels in other files. GCC generally uses .L for auto-generated labels. In this case most likely "`FB`" means "function begin" and "`FE`" means "function end".

Comment: very nice description indeed.