# GAS: Explanation of .cfi_def_cfa_offset

Tags: assembly, callstack, gnu-assembler, dwarf

I would like an explanation for the values used with the .cfi_def_cfa_offset directives in assembly generated by GCC. I know vaguely that the .cfi directives are involved in call frames and stack unwinding, but I would like a more detailed explanation of why, for example, the values 16 and 8 are used in the assembly outputted by GCC in compiling the following C program on my 64-bit Ubuntu machine.

The C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        printf("%d", 0);
        return 0;
}
```

I invoked GCC on the source file test.c as follows: `gcc -S -O3 test.c`. I know that -O3 enables nonstandard optimization, but I wanted to limit the size of the generated assembly for the sake of brevity.

The generated assembly:

```
        .file   "test.c"
        .section        .rodata.str1.1,"aMS",@progbits,1
.LC0:
        .string "%d"
        .text
        .p2align 4,,15
.globl main
        .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB22:
        .cfi_startproc
        subq    $8, %rsp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        xorl    %edx, %edx
        movl    $.LC0, %esi
        movl    $1, %edi
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        call    __printf_chk
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        addq    $8, %rsp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
        ret
            .cfi_endproc
.LFE22:
        .size   main, .-main
        .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) 4.5.2"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Why are the values 16 and 8 used for the .cfi_def_cfa_offset directives in the generated assembly? Also, why is the number 22 used for the local function begin and function end labels?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

As the [DWARF spec](http://dwarfstd.org/doc/DWARF4.pdf) says in section 6.4:

> [...] The call frame is 
>   identified by an address on the stack. We refer to this address as the Canonical Frame 
>   Address or CFA. Typically, the CFA is defined to be the value of the stack pointer at the 
>   call site in the previous frame (which may be different from its value on entry to the 
>   current frame).

`main()` is called from somewhere else (in the `libc` C runtime support code), and, at the time the `call` instruction is executed, `%rsp` will point to the top of the stack (which is the lowest address - the stack grows downwards), whatever that may be (exactly what it is doesn't matter here):

```
:                :                              ^
|    whatever    | <--- %rsp                    | increasing addresses
+----------------+                              |
```

The value of `%rsp` at this point is the "value of the stack pointer at the call site", i.e. the CFA as defined by the spec.

As the `call` instruction is executed, it will push a 64-bit (8 byte) return address onto the stack:

```
:                :
|    whatever    | <--- CFA
+----------------+
| return address | <--- %rsp == CFA - 8
+----------------+
```

Now we are running the code at `main`, which executes `subq $8, %rsp` to reserve another 8 bytes of stack for itself:

```
:                :
|    whatever    | <--- CFA
+----------------+
| return address |
+----------------+
| reserved space | <--- %rsp == CFA - 16
+----------------+
```

The change of stack pointer is declared in the debugging information using the `.cfi_def_cfa_offset` directive, and you can see that the CFA is now at an offset of 16 bytes from the current stack pointer.

At the end of the function, the `addq $8, %rsp` instruction changes the stack pointer again, so another `.cfi_def_cfa_offset` directive is inserted to indicate that the CFA is now at an offset of only 8 bytes from the stack pointer.

(The number "22" in the labels is just an arbitrary value.  The compiler will generate unique label names based on some implementation detail, such as its internal numbering of basic blocks.)

Comment: Indeed very good explanation. Commonly the labels are numbered sequentially (regarding function scope), here we may be seeing only those because the optimizer removed the other labels.

Comment: To understand the .cfi_* directives, you should also check out https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/CFI-directives.html.  It's thin, but it's official.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like an explanation for the values used with the `.cfi_def_cfa_offset` directives in assembly generated by GCC.

Matthew provided a good explanation. Here's the definition from [Section 7.10 CFI Directives](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/CFI-directives.html#CFI-directives) in the GAS manual:

> `.cfi_def_cfa_offset` modifies a rule for computing CFA. Register remains the same, but offset is new. Note that it is the absolute offset that will be added to a defined register to compute CFA address.

And `.cfi_adjust_cfa_offset`:

> Same as `.cfi_def_cfa_offset` but offset is a relative value that is added/substracted from the previous offset.