# implementation of .cfi_remember_state

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, x86-64, gnu-assembler

I was wondering how exactly `.cfi_remember_state` is implemented. I know it is a pseudo-op, so I suppose it is converted into a couple of instructions when assembling. I am interested what exact instructions are used to implement it. I tried many ways to figure it out. Namely:

- Read GAS source code. But failed to find anything useful enough.
- Read GAS documentation. But the `.cfi_remember_state` entry is just a simple joke (literally).
- Tried to find a gcc switch that would make gcc generate asm from C code with pseudo-ops "expanded". Failed to find such a switch for x86 / x86-64. (Would be nice if someone could point me to such a switch, assuming it exists, BTW.)
- Google-fu && searching on SO did not yield anything useful.

The only other solution in my mind would be to read the binary of an assembled executable file and try to deduce the instructions. Yet I would like to avoid such a daunting task.
Could any of You, who knows, enlighten me, how exactly it is implemented on x86 and/or x86-64? Maybe along with sharing how / where that information was acquired, so I could check other pseudo-ops, if I ever have the need to?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are CFI directives in Gnu Assembler (GAS) used for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529185/what-are-cfi-directives-in-gnu-assembler-gas-used-for)

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Yes, I am aware of this other question. But my question is different. I am not asking _what_ they are, but asking _how they are implemented_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This directive is a part of DWARF information (really all it does is emit DW_CFA_remember_state directive). Excerpt from DWARF3 standard:

> The DW_CFA_remember_state instruction takes no operands. The required
>   action is to push the set of rules for every register onto an implicit
>   stack.

You may play with DWARF information using objdump. Lets begin with simple void assembler file:

```
  .text
.globl main
  .type main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
.cfi_startproc
#.cfi_remember_state
.cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
  .size main, .-main
```

Compile it with `gcc cfirem.s -c -o cfirem.o`

Now disassemble generated DWARF section with `objdump --dwarf cfirem.o`
You will get:

```
00000018 00000014 0000001c FDE cie=00000000 pc=00000000..00000000
  DW_CFA_nop
  DW_CFA_nop
  ...
```

If you will uncomment .cfi_remember_state, you will see instead:

```
00000018 00000014 0000001c FDE cie=00000000 pc=00000000..00000000
  DW_CFA_remember_state
  DW_CFA_nop
  DW_CFA_nop
  ...
```

So it is not really converting in **assembler** instructions (try `objdump -d` to see that there are no assembler instructions in our sample at all). It is converted in DWARF pseudo-instructions, that are used when debugger like GDB processes your variable locations, stack information and so on.

Comment: Whoa this objdump is a useful tool! Did a similar test based on Your answer just now and I can see it _does_ generate 4 more instructions with `.cfi_remember_state`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I suppose you objdumped with -D, and those "four instructions" is really byte-to-byte representation of DW_CFA_remember_state inside .eh_frame section. It is not real assembler. Use -d to get real assembler only.

Comment: Oh! Now I see it! I assumed GCC generates no debug info by default, yet I noticed it still generates those when creating asm from C. So I thought it was used not only for debugging, but also for other purposes. Now that I looked over asm generated with -g0, they are no longer there. While gcc was defaulting to -g2 before all the time. Silly me!