# Understanding gcc -S output

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86-64

I did gcc -S on the very complex program below on x86_64:

```
int main() {
    int x = 3;
    x = 5;
    return 0;
}
```

And what I got was:

```
       .file   "main.c"
        .text
.globl main
        .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        pushq   %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
        movl    $3, -4(%rbp)
        movl    $5, -4(%rbp)
        movl    $0, %eax
        leave
        .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
        .size   main, .-main
        .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

I was wondering if someone could help me understand the output or refer me to some link explaining. Specifically, What does `cfi ,LFB0,LFE0 , leave` mean? All I could find regarding these is [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529185/what-are-cfi-directives-in-gnu-assembler-gas-used-for) but couldn't fully understand what it was for. Also, what does `ret` do in this case? I'm guessing it's returning to `__libc_start_main()` which in turn would call `do_exit()` , is that correct?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Those `.cfisomething` directives result in generation of additional data by the compiler. This data helps traverse the call stack when an instruction causes an exception, so the exception handler (if any) can be found and correctly executed. The call stack information is useful for debugging. This data most probably goes into a separate section of the executable. It's not inserted between the instructions of your code.

`.LFsomething:` are just regular labels that are probably referenced by that extra exception-related data.

`leave` and `ret` are CPU instructions.

`leave` is equivalent to:

```
movq    %rbp, %rsp
popq    %rbp
```

and it undoes the effect of these two instructions

```
pushq   %rbp
movq    %rsp, %rbp
```

and instructions that allocate space on the stack by subtracting something from `rsp`.

`ret` returns from the function. It pops the return address from the stack and jumps to that address. If it was `__libc_start_main()` that called `main()`, then it returns there.

Comment: On this architecture, all of GCC's local labels will start with `.L` and end with a number. Labels with only the `.L` and a number are jump targets; labels with some other letters in between have some other purpose. In this case, `FB` stands for "function begin" and `FE` stands for "function end", and they're *probably* not used for anything anymore. IIRC they used to be required when GCC calculated the exception handling data itself rather than having the assembler do it, and they're still in there because the x86 backend is very complicated so it's hard to be sure they're unnecessary.

Answer (score 16):

1. `.LFB0, .LFE0` are nothing but local labels.
2. `.cfi_startproc` is used at the beginning of each function and end of the function happens  by `.cfi_endproc`.

   - These assembler directives help the assembler to put debugging and stack unwinding information into the executable.
3. the `leave` instruction is an x86 assembler instruction which does the work of restoring the calling function's stack frame.

And lastly after the `ret` instruction, the following things happen:

- `%rip` contains return address
- `%rsp` points at arguments pushed by caller that didn't fit in the six registers used to pass arguments on amd64 (%rdi, %rsi, %rdx, %rcx, %r8, %r9)
- called function may have trashed arguments
- `%rax` contains return value (or trash if function is void) (or `%rax` and `%rdx` contain the return value if its size is >8 bytes but <=16 bytes<sup>1</sup>)
- `%r10`, `%r11` may be trashed
- `%rbp`, `%rbx`, `%r12`, `%r13`, `%r14`, `%r15` must contain contents from time of call

Additional information can be found [here (SO question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133812/where-is-the-x86-64-system-v-abi-documented) and [here (standards PDFs)](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI).

Or, on 32-bit:

- `%eip` contains return address
- `%esp` points at arguments pushed by caller
- called function may have trashed arguments
- `%eax` contains return value (or trash if function is void)
- `%ecx`, `%edx` may be trashed
- `%ebp`, `%ebx`, `%esi`, `%edi` must contain contents from time of call