# Failure of -mavx optimization with gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, avx

**EDIT** *partial solution below (EDIT 2), but I have still one question (see at the end)*

I am trying to compile the following C program with [gcc-4.9.2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/4.9.2/threads-win32/dwarf/), on Windows 7, 32 bits, running on a [Pentium G3220](http://ark.intel.com/products/77773) (according to Windows System Information). If I understand correctly, this processor does not have AVX extensions, so it's quite natural that something happens, I am just unsure about what exactly. Initially, I was playing with optimizations with gcc, and I tried -mavx rather "accidentally".

The following program computes permutations of numbers 0 ... n-1 (with n given as an argument) in lexicographic order, and also rank of each permutation (its position in this sequential order), and "unrank" (recover permutation from rank), and checks that all of these are correct. It should only print "OK" or "Error" in the end.

- With `gcc -O3`, the program runs correctly with all integer input I checked (1 <= n <= 11).
- With `gcc -O3 -mavx`, it runs correctly for 1 <= n <= 7, and for n >= 8, it prints nothing, and actually it does nothing (almost no delay before exiting). I get no message from the program or from Windows (I would have expected maybe a crash with an unknown instruction, but it didn't happen).

*(On another computer with Windows 7 64 bits, on a core-i5, and the same gcc-4.9.2, the program seems to run fine with of without -mavx, when compiled either in 32 or [64 bits](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/4.9.2/threads-win32/seh/))*

What I don't understand is why it runs correctly for some input values, and fails for other ones. Does anybody have some hint about this?

*Here is the full program, followed by a shorter one with the same problem.*

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define SWAP(a,b) {int c; c = a; a = b; b = c;}

int next_perm(int n, int a[n]) {
    int i, j, k;
    for(i = n - 1; i > 0 && a[i - 1] > a[i]; i--);
    for(j = i, k = n - 1; j < k; j++, k--) SWAP(a[j], a[k]);
    if(i == 0) return 0;
    for(j = i--; a[j] < a[i]; j++);
    SWAP(a[i], a[j]);
    return 1;
}

#undef SWAP

void copyvec(int n, int dst[n], int src[n]) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        dst[i] = src[i];
    }
}

int eqvec(int n, int a[n], int b[n]) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if(a[i] != b[i]) return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int rank(int n, int a[n]) {
    int v[n], i, j, r;
    v[n - 1] = 1;
    for(j = n - 2; j >= 0; j--) v[j] = v[j + 1]*(n - 1 - j);
    for(r = i = 0; ; i++) {
        for(j = i; j < n; j++) {
            if(a[j] > j) goto cont;

        }
        return r;
cont:
        i = j;
        r += v[i]*(a[i] - i);
        for(j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if(a[j] < a[i]) a[j]++;
        }
    }
}

void unrank(int n, int a[n], int p) {
    int v[n], i, j, r, s;
    v[n - 1] = 1;
    for(i = n - 2; i >= 0; i--) v[i] = v[i + 1]*(n - 1 - i);
    p %= n*v[0];
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) a[i] = i;
    for(i = 0; p > 0; i++) {
        for(; v[i] > p; i++);
        r = p/v[i];
        p %= v[i];
        for(s = a[j = i + r]; j >= i; j--) a[j] = a[j - 1];
        a[i] = s;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int n, i, r, s = 0, q = 0;
    int *a = NULL, *b = NULL, *c = NULL;
    if(argc == 2 && (n = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 0)) > 0) {
        a = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
        b = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
        c = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
        if(!a || !b || !c) {
            puts("Unable to allocate memory");
            goto end;
        } else {
            for(i = 0; i < n; i++) a[i] = i;
            do {
                copyvec(n, b, a);
                r = rank(n, b);
                unrank(n, c, r);
                q |= s++ != r || !eqvec(n, a, c);
            } while(next_perm(n, a));
            puts(q?"Error":"OK");
        }
    } else {
        puts("perm n - Check all permutations of {0 ... n - 1}, with n > 0");
    }
end:
    if(a) free(a);
    if(b) free(b);
    if(c) free(c);
    return 0;
}
```

---

**EDIT**

Following Brian Cain's comment, here is a shorter program with the same problem. I removed all checks on input value, all the rank/unrank stuff, and I replaced the malloc/free with an array of size 20 (only one now, since b and c are not used anymore). Now the program only computes the permutations with the `while(next_perm(n, a));` loop, and does nothing with them. It should still print "OK" in the end, though, because the value of q does not change after the initial q=0.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define SWAP(a,b) {int c; c = a; a = b; b = c;}

int next_perm(int n, int a[n]) {
    int i, j, k;
    for(i = n - 1; i > 0 && a[i - 1] > a[i]; i--);
    for(j = i, k = n - 1; j < k; j++, k--) SWAP(a[j], a[k]);
    if(i == 0) return 0;
    for(j = i--; a[j] < a[i]; j++);
    SWAP(a[i], a[j]);
    return 1;
}

#undef SWAP

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int n, i, r, s = 0, q = 0, a[20];
    n = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 0);
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) a[i] = i;
    while(next_perm(n, a));
    puts(q?"Error":"OK");
    return 0;
}
```

---

**EDIT 2: explanation of the assembly output**

I add also the disassembly output of gcc (in Intel syntax), found with `gcc -O3 -mavx -S -masm=intel` and gcc-4.9.2 (see link above for the actual binary files of the compiler). However, it needs some work, because as is, gcc will inline the call to next_perm, and it's less readable. I also remove the [CFI directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529185/what-are-cfi-directives-in-gnu-assembler-gas-used-for) and alignment and actually all other directives, to improve readability:

```
_next_perm:
LFB0:
    push    ebp
    push    edi
    push    esi
    push    ebx
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR [esp+20]
    mov edx, DWORD PTR [esp+24]
    lea eax, [ecx-1]
    test    eax, eax
    jle L12
    mov edi, DWORD PTR [edx-4+ecx*4]
    cmp DWORD PTR [edx-8+ecx*4], edi
    mov ecx, eax
    jg  L5
    jmp L11
L28:
    mov esi, DWORD PTR [edx+ecx*4]
    cmp DWORD PTR [edx-4+ecx*4], esi
    jle L27
L5:
    sub ecx, 1
    jne L28
L4:
    mov ebx, ecx
L7:
    mov esi, DWORD PTR [edx+ebx*4]
    mov edi, DWORD PTR [edx+eax*4]
    mov DWORD PTR [edx+ebx*4], edi
    mov DWORD PTR [edx+eax*4], esi
    add ebx, 1
    sub eax, 1
    cmp ebx, eax
    jl  L7
L2:
    xor eax, eax
    test    ecx, ecx
    je  L23
L11:
    sal ecx, 2
    lea esi, [edx+ecx]
    lea ebp, [edx-4+ecx]
    mov ebx, DWORD PTR [esi]
    mov edi, DWORD PTR [ebp+0]
    cmp edi, ebx
    jle L9
    lea eax, [edx+4+ecx]
L10:
    mov esi, eax
    add eax, 4
    mov ebx, DWORD PTR [eax-4]
    cmp ebx, edi
    jl  L10
L9:
    mov DWORD PTR [ebp+0], ebx
    mov eax, 1
    mov DWORD PTR [esi], edi
L23:
    pop ebx
    pop esi
    pop edi
    pop ebp
    ret
L27:
    cmp eax, ecx
    jg  L4
    jmp L11
L12:
    mov ecx, eax
    jmp L2
```

The assembly output is the same with or without -mavx, apart from label numbers: there is no AVX instruction, which means the problem actually lies in `main`.

This can be checked by adding some `puts` in main:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int n, i, q = 0, a[20];
    puts("X");
    n = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 0);
    puts("Y");
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) a[i] = i;
    puts("Z");
    while(next_perm(n, a));
    puts(q?"Error":"OK");
    return 0;
}
```

Then, the programs prints only X and Y when it fails, hence the problem comes from the AVX instructions used to build 'a' in the for loop between Y and Z.

Here is the assembly output of `main`, again without directives (LC2 points to "Y", and LC3 to "Z"). The only AVX instructions in the assembly ouptut of main are between those two `puts`, and they are used for the `for` loop that builds the initial 'a', that is the array {0, 1, ..., n-1}. What happens actually, is that AVX instructions are used to build several elements of 'a' at a time (4 I guess), and if the length of 'a' is not a multiple of 4, then there is an additional step (between L4 and L9), before calling the puts("Z") at L9, then the while(next_perm(n, a)); at L3. Thus, the problem is very simple: if `n` is small enough, then the AVX loop is actually not run, and there is no error. Here the maximum valid `n` is 4, but it varies between differents runs of gcc, it's a bit randomized it seems (I got 8 yesterday).

The LC0 and LC4 labels point to two arrays of 4 elements that are used by the AVX instructions: LC0 is {0,1,2,3}, and LC4 is {4,4,4,4}. No wonder why they are here, even without deep knowledge of AVX, it smells like an unrolled loop :-)

```
_main:
    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    push    edi
    push    esi
    push    ebx
    and esp, -16
    sub esp, 96
    call    ___main
    mov DWORD PTR [esp], OFFSET FLAT:LC1
    call    _puts
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [ebp+12]
    mov DWORD PTR [esp+8], 0
    mov DWORD PTR [esp+4], 0
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [eax+4]
    mov DWORD PTR [esp], eax
    call    _strtol
    mov DWORD PTR [esp], OFFSET FLAT:LC2
    mov ebx, eax
    call    _puts
    test    ebx, ebx
    jle L17
    lea edx, [ebx-4]
    lea ecx, [ebx-1]
    shr edx, 2
    add edx, 1
    cmp ecx, 3
    lea eax, [0+edx*4]
    jbe L10
    vmovdqa xmm1, XMMWORD PTR LC4
    lea esi, [esp+16]
    xor ecx, ecx
    vmovdqa xmm0, XMMWORD PTR LC0
L5:
    mov edi, ecx
    add ecx, 1
    sal edi, 4
    cmp edx, ecx
    vmovaps XMMWORD PTR [esi+edi], xmm0
    vpaddd  xmm0, xmm0, xmm1
    ja  L5
    cmp ebx, eax
    je  L9
L4:
    lea edx, [eax+1]
    mov DWORD PTR [esp+16+eax*4], eax
    cmp ebx, edx
    jle L9
    mov DWORD PTR [esp+16+edx*4], edx
    lea edx, [eax+2]
    cmp ebx, edx
    jle L9
    add eax, 3
    mov DWORD PTR [esp+16+edx*4], edx
    cmp ebx, eax
    jle L9
    mov DWORD PTR [esp+16+eax*4], eax
L9:
    mov DWORD PTR [esp], OFFSET FLAT:LC3
    call    _puts
L3:
    mov DWORD PTR [esp+4], esi
    mov DWORD PTR [esp], ebx
    call    _next_perm
    test    eax, eax
    jne L3
    mov DWORD PTR [esp], OFFSET FLAT:LC5
    call    _puts
    lea esp, [ebp-12]
    xor eax, eax
    pop ebx
    pop esi
    pop edi
    pop ebp
    ret
L10:
    xor eax, eax
    lea esi, [esp+16]
    jmp L4
L17:
    lea esi, [esp+16]
    jmp L9
```

Now, I understand what actually happens, but one question remains: why is there no error message whatsoever when the program tries to run an AVX instruction? It simply exits, or it's killed, but without any hint that something went wrong.

Comment: "I have no idea how to make it shorter while still showing this strange behaviour" -- I suggest bisecting the example, comparing against intermediate expected results in the good case.

Comment: @user3629249 Ahem, no. It finds the longest decreasing subsequence of 'a', starting from the last element. The rest of the algorithm is rather easy: reverse this subsequence, and swap the element just before with some element in the now increasing subsequence, so that it's still sorted. You get the next permutation in lexicographic order.

Comment: this loop: 'for(i = n - 1; i > 0 && a[i - 1] > a[i]; i--);' does nothing but waste CPU cycles and set i to some value in the range 1...n-1

Comment: @user3629249 No, the value of 'i' becomes 0 on one occasion (when the last permutation is hit: the whole of 'a' is decreasing). Since 'i' is used afterwards, I don't know how you can imagine the loop does nothing: it's sole purpose is finding 'i'. Maybe it's the semicolon after the 'for' that troubles you. C allows this.

Comment: @user3629249 As you probably know, `for(a;b;c) d` is exactly equivalent to `a; while(b) { d; c; }`. Any of "a", "b", "c" may be missing in the for loop, and "d" may be reduced to a single semicolon.

Comment: Have you looked at the disassembly? What are the differences that the compiler generates?

Comment: @Degustaf I tried, but while I know some 32 bit assembler, I know almost nothing about SSE/AVX instructions, so I am not able to follow the output.

Comment: AFAIK, running an application that has AVX specific assembly on a processor that does not support it, crashes the application with an error like "Invalid instruction". Could you post here the dissasembly? SSE and AVX instructions can be identified by looking at the usage of registers (%xmm / %ymm, respectively), and being packed (p) instructions (addps -> add packed single, mulpd -> multiply, packed double)

Comment: @CristianoSousa Done. If you prefer att syntax, I'll change the assembly output.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut please post both versions (with and witouth -mavx)

Comment: W.r.t. your last question: Easy. It would be outrageous (and slow) to put a runtime check before each SSE/AVX instruction to verify that the CPU supports its instruction set. Your use of `-mavx` is a promise that the binary will only run on CPUs that do support AVX; If this is not the case, an x86 CPU raises the exception `#UD` (Undefined Opcode), to which the OS reacts by serving the guilty process with the `SIGILL` (Illegal Instruction) signal, whose default action is Abort.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist It seems perfectly correct to do so. However, gcc *could* put a test at the beginning of main, since it knows AVX instructions are used (it would probably need some work to do it at link time, in case the AVX instruction are hidden in an object file). Anyway, I thought the illegal instruction would make Windows cry, with maybe a window showing the reason of the crash, or at least a meassage in the command prompt. So, what you mean is that a SIGILL will make the program abort silently, right?

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist Actually, it has to be as simple as that. A quick check shows me that even division by 0, or dereferencing a null pointer, aborts silently. I thought that there were messages by default, maybe because of my past Linux experience (I guess they would print a message in Linux?)

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I was about to suggest to you that you write a simple program that calls `raise(SIGILL)` against itself and see if this aborts silently.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist And you are right of course, it aborts silently. Thank you very much! I had really a wrong idea about how exceptions are treated by default.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist Btw, you can ake this an answer, so that the question is not left without one.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist, yes, please post an answer.

Comment: When I create a simple console app that uses AVX2 on my system without AVX2 with MSVC 2013 on Windows 7 and run it the program does not abort silently. I get an error message.

Comment: @Zboson But I haven't contributed to the first part of the question and besides am unsure of the Windows rules for silent aborts and displaying crash windows... It's past where I can authoritatively answer.

Comment: @Zboson Maybe MSVC adds default handlers for exceptions? You can try to add your own to disable the default one, see the doc for [signal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdkz3x12.aspx). Here I was testing with gcc, which may have a different behaviour. You may also try to see what really happens with a debugger.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, yeah, MinGW-w64 may do something differently than MSVC.

Comment: **TL:DR summary of comments**: It's normal for illegal instructions to make your process exit silently on Windows, unlike Linux.  This is what happens when your program runs an AVX instruction on a system that doesn't support them.

Answer (score -2):

```
This code always results in:
where parameter = n
a[] = {0,0,2, 3, ...,n-2,n-1}
b[] = {n-1, n-1, ... , n-1}
c[] = {n-1, n-2, ... , 0}
when it reaches the above conditions,
then it exits with "OK"

the amount of time spent executing the code 
climbs at an exponential rate
as the value of the parameter is increased
```

Comment: Actually, no, 'a' is the array {0, **1**, ... n-1} in the end, because when next_perm hits the last (which is decreasing), it reverses it *before* returning, so 'a' is reset to it's initial state. My question is not really about what the program does, as I wrote it: `next_perm` finds the next permutation in lexicographic order. `rank` computes the position of a permutation in the list of all permutations, and `unrank` does the converse (compute the perm from its position). Since there are n! permutations and the program enumerates all of them, the time spent grows even more than exponentially.

Comment: Also, as I explained in the question, I wrote the program to test that the 3 functions `next_perm`, `rank` and `unrank` do correctly their job: it computes all permutations in lexicographic order with next_perm, and for each one, stored in 'a', it computes it's position, which must be the correct position (0, 1, ... n! - 1), and it computes back the permutation from this position, and it must be equal to 'a'. I copy 'a' before calling rank, because the function destroys its input.

Comment: Just an example of what [lexicographic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) (or dictionary order) means here. For n=3, the permutations are
0 1 2 ; 0 2 1 ; 1 0 2 ; 1 2 0 ; 2 0 1 ; 2 1 0. There are 3!=6 of them.