# GCC Assembly Optimizations - Why are these equivalent?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86-64, gnu-assembler

I am trying to learn how assembly works at an elementary level and so I have been playing with the `-S` output of gcc compilations.  I wrote a simple program that defines two bytes and returns their sum.  The entire program follows:

```
int main(void) {
  char A = 5;
  char B = 10;
  return A + B;
}
```

When I compile this with no optimizations using:

```
gcc -O0 -S -c test.c
```

I get test.s that looks like the following:

```
    .file   "test.c"
    .def    ___main;    .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .text
    .globl  _main
    .def    _main;  .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
_main:
LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    andl    $-16, %esp
    subl    $16, %esp
    call    ___main
    movb    $5, 15(%esp)
    movb    $10, 14(%esp)
    movsbl  15(%esp), %edx
    movsbl  14(%esp), %eax
    addl    %edx, %eax
    leave
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
LFE0:
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.9.2"
```

Now, recognizing that this program can very easily be simplified to just return a constant (15) I have been able to reduce the assembly by hand to perform the same function using this code:

```
.global _main
_main:
    movl    $15, %eax
    ret
```

This appears to me to be the least amount of code possible (but I realize could be quite wrong) to perform this admittedly trivial task.  Is this form the most "optimized" version of my C program?

**Why is the initial output of GCC so much more verbose?  What do the lines spanning from `.cfi_startproc` to `call __main` even do?  What does `call __main` do?  I cannot figure what the two subtraction operations are for.**

Even with optimizations in GCC set to `-O3` I get this:

```
    .file   "test.c"
    .def    ___main;    .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .section    .text.unlikely,"x"
LCOLDB0:
    .section    .text.startup,"x"
LHOTB0:
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  _main
    .def    _main;  .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
_main:
LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    andl    $-16, %esp
    call    ___main
    movl    $15, %eax
    leave
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
LFE0:
    .section    .text.unlikely,"x"
LCOLDE0:
    .section    .text.startup,"x"
LHOTE0:
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.9.2"
```

Which seems to have removed a number of operations, but still leaves all the lines leading to `call __main` that seems unnecessary.  **What are all the `.cfi_XXX` lines for?  Why are so many labels added?  What do `.section`, `.ident`, `.def .p2align`, etc. do?**

I understand that many of the labels and symbols are included for debugging, but shouldn't these be stripped or omitted if I am not compiling with -g enabled?

---

**UPDATE**

To clarify, by saying

> This appears to me to be the least amount of code possible (but I
> realize could be quite wrong) to perform this admittedly trivial task.
> Is this form the most "optimized" version of my C program?

I am not suggesting that I am trying to, or have achieved, an optimized version of this program.  I realize the program is useless and trivial.  I am just using it as a tool to learn assembly and how the compiler works.

The core of why I added this bit is to illustrate why I am confused that the 4 line version of this assembly code can effectively achieve the same effect as the others.  It seems to me that GCC has added a lot of "stuff" whose purpose I cannot discern.

Comment: Debug. Optimization is the debugger worst enemy. All those redundant, well documented lines make debugging assembly as easy as debugging C. For the second question, C programs use the C run time, they need to obey an ABI and may use OS specific features.

Comment: @WeatherVane My intent was not to suggest that this program either made sense or was useful in any way, I am just using it as a tool for learning assembly and how the compiler works.

Comment: @Kin3TiX sorry, deleted my crass remark.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thank you, Kin3TiX, for asking an asm-newbie question that wasn't just a code-dump of some nasty code with no comments, and a really simple problem. :)

As a way to get your feet wet with ASM, I'd suggest working with functions OTHER than `main`.  e.g. just a function that takes two integer args, and adds them.  Then the compiler can't optimize it away.  You can still call it with constants as args, and if it's in a different file from `main`, it won't get inlined, so you can even single-step through it.

There's some benefit to understanding what's going on at the asm level when you compile `main`, but other than embedded systems, you're only ever going to write optimized inner loops in asm.  IMO, there's little point using asm if you aren't going to optimize the hell out of it.  Otherwise you probably won't beat compiler output from source which is much easier to read.

Other tips for understanding compiler output: compile with
`gcc -S -fno-stack-check -fverbose-asm`.  The comments after each instruction are often nice reminders of what that load was for.  Pretty soon it degenerates into a mess of temporaries with names like `D.2983`, but something like
`movq    8(%rdi), %rcx   # a_1(D)->elements, a_1(D)->elements` will save you a round-trip to the ABI reference to see which function arg comes in in `%rdi`, and which struct member is at offset 8.

See also [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output)

---

> What do the lines spanning from .cfi_startproc to call__main even do?

```
    _main:
LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
```

`.cfi` stuff is stack-unwind info for debuggers (and C++ exception handling) to unwind the stack
It won't be there if you look at asm from `objdump -d` output instead of `gcc -S`, or you can use `-fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables`.

The stuff with pushing `%ebp` and then setting it to the value of the stack pointer on function entry sets up what's called a "stack frame".  This is why `%ebp` is called the base pointer.  These insns won't be there if you compile with `-fomit-frame-pointer`, which gives code an extra register to work with.  That's on by default at `-O2`.  (This is huge for 32bit x86, since that takes you from 6 to 7 usable regs.  (`%esp` is still tied up being the stack pointer;  stashing it temporarily in an xmm or mmx reg and then using it as another GP reg is possible in theory, but compilers will never do that and it makes async stuff like POSIX signals or Windows SEH unusable, as well as making debugging harder.)

The `leave` instruction before the `ret` is also part of this stack frame stuff.

Frame pointers are mostly historical baggage, but do make offsets into the stack frame consistent.  With debug symbols, you can backtrace the call stack just fine even with `-fomit-frame-pointer`, and it's the default for amd64.  (The amd64 ABI has alignment requirements for the stack, is a LOT better in other ways, too.  e.g. passes args in regs instead of on the stack.)

```
    andl    $-16, %esp
    subl    $16, %esp
```

The `and` aligns the stack to a 16-byte boundary, regardless of what it was before.  The `sub` reserves 16 bytes on the stack for this function.  (Notice how it's missing from the optimized version, because it optimizes away any need for memory storage of any variables.)

```
    call    ___main
```

`__main` (asm name = `___main`) is part of cygwin: it calls constructor / init functions for shared libraries (including libc).  On GNU/Linux, this is handled by `_start` (before main is reached) and even dynamic-linker hooks that let libc initialize itself before the executable's own `_start` is even reached.  I've read that dynamic-linker hooks (or `_start` from a static executable) instead of code in `main` *would* be possible under Cygwin, but they simply choose not to do it that way.

(This [old mailing list message](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2007-09/msg00110.html) indicates `_main` is for constructors, but that main shouldn't have to call it on platforms that support getting the startup code to call it.)

```
    movb    $5, 15(%esp)
    movb    $10, 14(%esp)
    movsbl  15(%esp), %edx
    movsbl  14(%esp), %eax
    addl    %edx, %eax
    leave
    ret
```

> Why is the initial output of GCC so much more verbose?

Without optimizations enabled, gcc maps C statements as literally as possible into asm.  Doing anything else would take more compile time.  Thus, `movb` is from the initializers for your two variables.  The return value is computed by doing two loads (with sign extension, because we need to upconvert to int BEFORE the add, to match the semantics of the C code as written, as far as overflow).

> I cannot figure what the two subtraction operations are for.

There is only one `sub` instruction.  It reserves space on the stack for the function's variables, before the call to `__main`.  Which other sub are you talking about?

> What do .section, .ident, .def .p2align, etc. etc. do?

See the [manual for the GNU assembler](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/).  Also available locally as info pages:  run `info gas`.

`.ident` and `.def`: Looks like gcc putting its stamp on the object file, so you can tell what compiler / assembler produced it.  Not relevant, ignore these.

`.section`: determines what section of the ELF object file the bytes from all following instructions or data directives (e.g. `.byte 0x00`) go into, until the next `.section` assembler directive.  Either `code` (read-only, shareable), `data` (initialized read/write data, private), or `bss` (block storage segment.  zero-initialized, doesn't take any space in the object file).

`.p2align`: Power of 2 Align.  Pad with nop instructions until the desired alignment.  `.align 16` is the same as `.p2align 4`.  Jump instruction are faster when the target is aligned, because of instruction fetch in chunks of 16B, not crossing a page boundary, or just not crossing a cache-line boundary.  (32B alignment is relevant when code is already in the uop cache of an Intel Sandybridge and later.)  See [Agner Fog's docs](http://agner.org/optimize/), for example.

> The core of why I added this bit is to illustrate why I am confused
> that the 4 line version of this assembly code can effectively achieve
> the same effect as the others. It seems to me that GCC has added alot
> of "stuff" whose purpose I cannot discern.

Put the code of interest in a function by itself.  A lot of things are special about `main`.

You are correct that a `mov`-immediate and a `ret` are all that's needed to implement the function, but gcc apparently doesn't have shortcuts for recognizing trivial whole-programs and omitting `main`'s stack frame or the call to `_main`.  >.<

Good question, though.  As I said, just ignore all that crap and worry about just the small part you want to optimize.

Comment: update on this, `.cfi` isn't strictly debug info, and isn't stripped.  It's stack-unwind info that says which call-preserved register is saved where.  See also [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](//stackoverflow.com/q/38552116) for more about removing "noise" like .cfi directives that you normally don't care about.

Answer (score 6):

`.cfi` (call frame information) directives are used in `gas` (Gnu ASsembler) mainly for debugging. They allow the debugger to unwind the stack. To disable them, you can use the following parameter when you invoke the compilation driver `-fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables`.

If you want to play with the compiler in general, you can use the following compilation driver invocation command `-o <filename.S> -S -masm=intel -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables <filename.C>` or just use [godbolt's interactive compiler](http://gcc.godbolt.org/)

Comment: The interactive compiler is incredibly helpful.  In particular, the colorize feature has allowed me to directly see which assembly instructions are generated directly from the lines of my source.  The other answers have subsequently helped me isolate all the other "stuff" that ends up in there.

Comment: @Kin3TiX Glad that I have been of help.

Answer (score 1):

First off, the CFI stuff is there for debugging purposes (and, in C++, exception handling). It tells the debugger what the stack frame looks like at each instruction, so that the debugger can reconstruct the state of the program's variables. Those don't result in executable statements, and will have zero effect on a program's runtime performance.

I don't know what the call to `__main` is doing there - my GCC doesn't do that. In fact, my GCC (4.9.2) gives me the following for `gcc test.c -S -O1`:

```
    .section __TEXT,__text_startup,regular,pure_instructions
    .globl _main
_main:
LFB0:
    movl    $15, %eax
    ret
LFE0:
    .section __TEXT,__eh_frame,coalesced,no_toc+strip_static_syms+live_support
EH_frame1:
    .set L$set$0,LECIE1-LSCIE1
    .long L$set$0
LSCIE1:
    .long   0
    .byte   0x1
    .ascii "zR\0"
    .byte   0x1
    .byte   0x78
    .byte   0x10
    .byte   0x1
    .byte   0x10
    .byte   0xc
    .byte   0x7
    .byte   0x8
    .byte   0x90
    .byte   0x1
    .align 3
LECIE1:
LSFDE1:
    .set L$set$1,LEFDE1-LASFDE1
    .long L$set$1
LASFDE1:
    .long   LASFDE1-EH_frame1
    .quad   LFB0-.
    .set L$set$2,LFE0-LFB0
    .quad L$set$2
    .byte   0
    .align 3
LEFDE1:
    .subsections_via_symbols
```

and would you look at that, `_main` is exactly the two-instruction sequence you expected. (The `__eh_frame` stuff is more debugging information in a different format).

Answer (score 1):

The `-o0` option directs the output to a file named `0`.  Maybe you meant the optimization level (which is capital *O*)?:  that disables optimizations.

I don't understand why there would be a call to `____main` unless this was produced for some emulated or hooked environment.  When I compile with `gcc -O0 -c -S t.c`, I get:

```
        .file   "t.c"
        .text
.globl main
        .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        pushq   %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
        movb    $5, -2(%rbp)
        movb    $10, -1(%rbp)
        movsbl  -2(%rbp), %edx
        movsbl  -1(%rbp), %eax
        leal    (%rdx,%rax), %eax
        leave
        .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
        .size   main, .-main
        .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Perhaps you were expecting a high level of optimization?  This is what I get with `gcc -O3 -c -S t.c`:

```
        .file   "t.c"
        .text
        .p2align 4,,15
.globl main
        .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        movl    $15, %eax
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
        .size   main, .-main
        .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Except for the debug information, it is about as short as it can be.  The same code is produced for `gcc -O2 -c -S t.c` and `gcc -O1 -c -S t.c`.  That is, the slightest optimization evaluates all the constants at compile time.

Comment: I did have a capital -O...?  Regardless, I think your answer explains the __main to me.  I ran this on Cygwin (at work so I'm not on my Linux box atm), so that would support your comment about running on an emulated or hooked environment.

Answer (score 0):

I think that part is just a fixed pattern that sets up a 16-byte aligned stack and the CFI is [exception frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529185/what-are-cfi-directives-in-gnu-assembler-gas-used-for) handling related.

Determining that those are not needed for any main() is hard since that is a global optimization because main might call functions in other compilation units.

And it is probably not worthwhile spending the time to optimize this trivial and fairly useless case.

If you feel otherwise, you can always start working on such an optimization and submit it to gcc.

Comment: An exception frame sounds more like C++, as C does not have exceptions. But that may be really just a common template for both languages.

Comment: Not trying to suggest that I was able to "optimize" this example...just trying to understand why I can strip that assembly down to so few lines and still have it work.  It makes me wonder what all the other stuff is doing in there, which was the crux of my question.

Comment: Then put all code that you are interested in in separate functions, and compile that with high optimization. For the startup and main code sometimes other rules and tradeoffs exists and that might skew what happens, as you found out.