# Why does GCC not add .section into the assembly

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

If you look at the second line of this program it just says "`.text`".  When I write assembly programs I though that you had to put "`.section .text`"  Why does `GCC` omit the "`.section`".  I also noticed that it includes it before declaring rodata bellow  "`.section    .rodata`".

Also just wondering what "`.type   sum`, `@function`" does?  I wrote an assembly function this morning without it and it executed fine.

```
.file   "test.c"
        .text
        .globl  sum
        .type   sum, @function
    sum:
    .LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        pushq   %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
        movss   %xmm0, -4(%rbp)
        movss   %xmm1, -8(%rbp)
        movss   -4(%rbp), %xmm0
        mulss   -8(%rbp), %xmm0
        cvttss2si   %xmm0, %eax
        popq    %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
    .LFE0:
        .size   sum, .-sum
        .section    .rodata
    .LC2:
        .string "%d\n"
        .text
        .globl  main
        .type   main, @function
    main:
    .LFB1:
        .cfi_startproc
        pushq   %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
        subq    $16, %rsp
        movss   .LC0(%rip), %xmm1
        movss   .LC1(%rip), %xmm0
        call    sum
        movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)
        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
        movl    %eax, %esi
        movl    $.LC2, %edi
        movl    $0, %eax
        call    printf
        movl    $0, %eax
        leave
        .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
    .LFE1:
        .size   main, .-main
        .section    .rodata
        .align 4
    .LC0:
        .long   1092930765
        .align 4
    .LC1:
        .long   1092825907
        .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.9.2-10ubuntu13) 4.9.2"
        .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Comment: You can use `.text` too. The assembler doesn't know it has been put there by a compiler or a human ;) It's basically an alias for `.section .text` if you don't specify a subsection number. The `.type` just sets the symbol type so that it is marked as defining a function (mostly relevant for shared libraries).

Comment: You may also find the gnu Assembler reference helpful: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.20/as/

Comment: The names of the standard sections are keywords, too for simplicity and backwards compatibility. Note some earlier object file formats did not allow for arbitrary sections and had only `.text`, `.bss`, `.data`.

Comment: I don't understand the downvoting for this question. It's entirely reasonable, given that both notations work, and gcc on OSX/Darwin *does* emit `.section` directives for Mach-O assembler - which uses an essentially unmodified x86-64 ELF ABI.

Answer (score 2):

Collecting up some comments into an answer:

Before arbitrary section names were possible, `.text`, `.data`, and `.bss` were assembler directives.  Now, you can write `.section .text` instead.  This should all be documented [in the GNU `as` manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/).  (linked to latest version).

```
    .type   sum, @function
```

sets some ELF symbol-type stuff.  IDK if this matters for dynamic linking, but it doesn't for static linkage.  There's a *lot* of stuff the compiler emits but that you don't actually need for your code to run.  This is not a bad thing.

For the other things in gcc asm output, have a look at my answer to [GCC Assembly Optimizations - Why are these equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31166773/gcc-assembly-optimizations-why-are-these-equivalent/31193524#31193524)