# Why is inline changing the assembly code in this way?

Tags: c++, assembly, inline

I wrote a very simple C++ program to understand how "inline" works:

```
inline int square(int x) {
    return x*x;
}

int main() {
    int y = square(1234);
    return y;
}
```

I compiled it to assembly code without and with the "inline". Strangely, in both cases a function was generated, but it was different. Without the inline the code looks like this (removing most comments):

```
_Z6squarei:                             # @_Z6squarei
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
    movl    -4(%rbp), %edi
    imull   -4(%rbp), %edi
    movl    %edi, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    retq
.Lfunc_end0:

main:                                   # @main
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movl    $1234, %edi             # imm = 0x4D2
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    callq   _Z6squarei
    movl    %eax, -8(%rbp)
    movl    -8(%rbp), %eax
    addq    $16, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    retq
.Lfunc_end1:
```

With the inline, it looks like this:

```
main:                                   # @main
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
.Lcfi0:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
.Lcfi1:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
.Lcfi2:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movl    $1234, %edi             # imm = 0x4D2
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    callq   _Z6squarei
    movl    %eax, -8(%rbp)
    movl    -8(%rbp), %eax
    addq    $16, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    retq
.Lfunc_end0:

_Z6squarei:                             # @_Z6squarei
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
    movl    -4(%rbp), %edi
    imull   -4(%rbp), %edi
    movl    %edi, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    retq
.Lfunc_end1:
```

It is very similar, except the new "cfi" directives. Why are they there only when I use "inline"?

And a second question: is there a way to tell the compiler to really make this function inline? (I am using clang++-5.0).

Comment: What optimization flags are you running with?  If you have optimization set to zero or debug, the compiler won't inline anything, because it makes setting breakpoints difficult.  Try with `-O2` or `-Os` and check the generated assembly again.

Comment: `inline` is just a hint to the compiler.  The optimizer decides to inline your function based on a number of things, the `inline` keyword may or may not be taken into account.  If you are compiling with optimizations turned off (as in your assembly listing), the optimizer doesn't run and no functions are actually inlined.  Don't do that.  Also, without optimizations, the generated code might be fairly weird and pointless.  This is because you forbade the compiler from optimizing away these quirks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529185/what-are-cfi-directives-in-gnu-assembler-gas-used-for

Comment: _is there a way to tell the compiler to really make this function inline?_  No, Inline is just a request to compiler not an order.

Comment: The [`inline` keyword](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline) have always been just a hint for the compiler in regards to the actual inlining. It might do other things though (which is probably the reason behind the difference in generated code).

Comment: @achal: True that `inline` is just a hint, but that doesn't preclude a different stronger way.  [`__attribute__(always_inline)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8381293/103167)   But forcing inline isn't needed here, just enabling optimization.

Comment: In this particular case the optimizer will still very likely not inline the function call. Because it will rather calculate the value, so it will probably compile it as: `int main() { return 1522756; }` (which is the correct and most reasonable thing to do).

Comment: @Ped7g indeed, this is what happens when I use the -O2 flag! So, how can I see inline at work?

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi Use an example that can't be optimized away.

Comment: The keyword `inline` does not mean what it used to. Now it means only that if the LINKER is presented with definitions of the same function from different compilation units, it is to choose one, rather than raising a `one definition rule` error.  It no longer has anything to do with what the compiler does. Any given compiler is free to do what it pleases regarding expanding a function in line, as long as it follows the `as if` rule of course.

Comment: `inline` is a *linking* and ODR thing. It doesn't actually mean anything regarding inlining of your code. Just a FYI.

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi well... what fuz said. But overall it is not clear, why do you care, if you don't have particular problem with some real source. You should have first a real problem, when you want to check anything about optimization and performance, the artificial example sources may easily lead you to wrong conclusions. Not sure what you are pursuing. If you are studying compilers and optimizations, and you want some example, then just rebuild any small app you have in your OS (if you have OSS OS) locally, and check object files vs the original source (search the src for interesting parts)

Comment: @JiveDadson I did not understand.... can you give me a link to learn more about this?

Comment: @achal - In the ISO Standard, `inline` is no longer even a request for the compiler to expand a function in-line. It is a requirement on the linker not to raise certain ODR errors.

Comment: @Erel Segal-Halevi http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline

Comment: @achal: Not in ISO C++, but GNU C++ has `__attribute__((always_inline))`, which may work even at `-O0`.

Comment: @Erel: You can see in this example (https://godbolt.org/g/Y5kPV9) that `inline` lets the compiler not emit a stand-alone definition of `square` when it does choose to inline into a caller.  (Also an example of using a function with an arg so it doesn't optimize away.  Related: see Matt Godbolt's CppCon2017 talk: [“What Has My Compiler Done for Me Lately? Unbolting the Compiler's Lid”](https://youtu.be/bSkpMdDe4g4) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output.

Comment: IDK why your compiler didn't emit CFI directives in `main` when you didn't use `inline`.  That seems odd.  But are you really interested in debug / stack-unwind metadata?  It is the only thing in the question that's not easily explained, but I think you were more interested in what exactly `inline` means, and thought it would do something even without enabling optimization.

Comment: I expect that replacing `inline` with `static` will give the same results, when compiling with -O2 or -O3. In both cases, the compile will see no reason not to inline the only single call site of a function like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
unsigned int fun0 ( unsigned int );

static unsigned int fun1 ( unsigned int x )
{
    return(x+1);
}

unsigned int fun2 ( unsigned int x )
{
    return(x+2);
}

inline unsigned int fun3 ( unsigned int x )
{
    return(x+3);
}

unsigned int hello ( unsigned int x )
{
    unsigned int y;
    y=fun0(x);
    y=fun1(y);
    y=fun2(y);
    y=fun3(y);
    return(y);
}
```

Intentionally using a different instruction set:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <fun2>:
   0:   e2800002    add r0, r0, #2
   4:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00000008 <hello>:
   8:   e92d4010    push    {r4, lr}
   c:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <fun0>
  10:   e8bd4010    pop {r4, lr}
  14:   e2800006    add r0, r0, #6
  18:   e12fff1e
```

fun0() is external the compiler doesnt have visibility there it has to setup a call and take the return value.

fun1() is marked as static so we have indicated we want that function to be local to this object/file/scope so there is no reason for the compiler to create a function there for others to remotely access, and the optimizer can see the function it is in the same file so chooses to inline it.

fun2() has no special markings it is assumed global so the compiler needs to provide code that performs that function for others to possibly consume, but at the same time the optimizer sees that function, it is in the same file, so optimizes it as inline as well as fun1.

fun3() we indicated the compiler can inline this one, somewhat implying that it is for consumption in this scope, so like static the compiler did not generate code for global consumption, and optimized (inlined)

functionally hello takes x sends it to fun0() which turns it into y.  we then add 1+2+3 = 6 to it.  So to inline fun1, fun2, fun3 you simply add 6 to the output of fun0().  And that is what we see fun1() fun2() and fun3() are inlined.

Maybe the confusion here is what inline means it means in line.  Dont call the funtion include the functionality in line with the caller.

```
unsigned int fun2 ( unsigned int x )
{
    return(x+2);
}

unsigned int hello ( unsigned int x )
{
    return(fun2(x));
}
```

with the tool I am using I didnt actually need to ask it to inline

```
00000000 <fun2>:
   0:   e2800002    add r0, r0, #2
   4:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00000008 <hello>:
   8:   e2800002    add r0, r0, #2
   c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

the optimizer did it anywa, instead of setting up a call to fun2 it took the functionality of fun2 which was to add 2 to the operand, and it simply did that in hello IN LINE.

With your tool notice the global function is created either way, but when you asked it to inline it doesnt look like it actually did anything, check the disassembly along with the assembly, the disassembly is usually easier to read, less confusing.

Note, using my first example and a C++ compiler so I dont get a "hey you didnt use a C++ compiler":

```
0000000000000000 <_Z4fun2j>:
   0:   8d 47 02                lea    0x2(%rdi),%eax
   3:   c3                      retq   
   4:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
   6:   66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
   d:   00 00 00 

0000000000000010 <_Z5helloj>:
  10:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
  14:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  19 <_Z5helloj+0x9>
  19:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
  1d:   83 c0 06                add    $0x6,%eax
  20:   c3                      retq
```

Same story, the inline and static did not produce a global function for others to use.  And the compiler generated a call for the external function, then added 6 to that.

Note no optimization:

```
00000000 <fun1>:
   0:   e52db004    push    {r11}       ; (str r11, [sp, #-4]!)
   4:   e28db000    add r11, sp, #0
   8:   e24dd00c    sub sp, sp, #12
   c:   e50b0008    str r0, [r11, #-8]
  10:   e51b3008    ldr r3, [r11, #-8]
  14:   e2833001    add r3, r3, #1
  18:   e1a00003    mov r0, r3
  1c:   e28bd000    add sp, r11, #0
  20:   e49db004    pop {r11}       ; (ldr r11, [sp], #4)
  24:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00000028 <fun2>:
  28:   e52db004    push    {r11}       ; (str r11, [sp, #-4]!)
  2c:   e28db000    add r11, sp, #0
  30:   e24dd00c    sub sp, sp, #12
  34:   e50b0008    str r0, [r11, #-8]
  38:   e51b3008    ldr r3, [r11, #-8]
  3c:   e2833002    add r3, r3, #2
  40:   e1a00003    mov r0, r3
  44:   e28bd000    add sp, r11, #0
  48:   e49db004    pop {r11}       ; (ldr r11, [sp], #4)
  4c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00000050 <hello>:
  50:   e92d4800    push    {r11, lr}
  54:   e28db004    add r11, sp, #4
  58:   e24dd010    sub sp, sp, #16
  5c:   e50b0010    str r0, [r11, #-16]
  60:   e51b0010    ldr r0, [r11, #-16]
  64:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <fun0>
  68:   e50b0008    str r0, [r11, #-8]
  6c:   e51b0008    ldr r0, [r11, #-8]
  70:   ebffffe2    bl  0 <fun1>
  74:   e50b0008    str r0, [r11, #-8]
  78:   e51b0008    ldr r0, [r11, #-8]
  7c:   ebfffffe    bl  28 <fun2>
  80:   e50b0008    str r0, [r11, #-8]
  84:   e51b0008    ldr r0, [r11, #-8]
  88:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <fun3>
  8c:   e50b0008    str r0, [r11, #-8]
  90:   e51b3008    ldr r3, [r11, #-8]
  94:   e1a00003    mov r0, r3
  98:   e24bd004    sub sp, r11, #4
  9c:   e8bd4800    pop {r11, lr}
  a0:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

calls them all no inlining...what optimization did you use in your test?  What if you try optimizing? (llvm/clang gives you multiple optimization opportunities over gnu)

EDIT using llvm and optimization.

two separate files

```
unsigned int fun0 ( unsigned int x )
{
    return(x+7);
}
```

and this one

```
unsigned int fun0 ( unsigned int );

inline unsigned int fun3 ( unsigned int x )
{
    return(x+3);
}

unsigned int hello ( unsigned int x )
{
    unsigned int y;
    y=fun0(x);
    y=fun3(y);
    return(y);
}
```

build without optimization

0000000000000000 :
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   89 7d fc                mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)
   7:   8d 47 07                lea    0x7(%rdi),%eax
   a:   5d                      pop    %rbp
   b:   c3                      retq

and

```
0000000000000000 <hello>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
   8:   89 7d fc                mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)
   b:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  10 <hello+0x10>
  10:   89 45 f8                mov    %eax,-0x8(%rbp)
  13:   89 c7                   mov    %eax,%edi
  15:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  1a <hello+0x1a>
  1a:   89 45 f8                mov    %eax,-0x8(%rbp)
  1d:   48 83 c4 10             add    $0x10,%rsp
  21:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  22:   c3                      retq
```

post compile was hoping for fun0 to be inlined, oh well, it did optimize hello

```
0000000000000000 <fun0>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   8d 47 07                lea    0x7(%rdi),%eax
   7:   5d                      pop    %rbp
   8:   c3                      retq   
   9:   0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax)

0000000000000010 <hello>:
  10:   55                      push   %rbp
  11:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  14:   83 c7 07                add    $0x7,%edi
  17:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  1c <hello+0xc>
  1c:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  1d:   c3                      retq
```

compiled with optimizations.

```
0000000000000000 <fun0>:
   0:   8d 47 07                lea    0x7(%rdi),%eax
   3:   c3                      retq   

0000000000000000 <hello>:
   0:   50                      push   %rax
   1:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  6 <hello+0x6>
   6:   83 c0 03                add    $0x3,%eax
   9:   59                      pop    %rcx
   a:   c3                      retq
```

clang gives you different optimization opportunities.

Okay that got it, as your number of files increases the optimization combinations for llvm tools goes up near exponentially, for bigger projects I found if you compile unoptimized it gives the later optimizer more meat to work with, but of course it depends on a number of factors, and unfortunately the combinations become staggering.  If I compile with optimizations first then combine and optimize later I get what I wanted.

```
0000000000000000 <fun0>:
   0:   8d 47 07                lea    0x7(%rdi),%eax
   3:   c3                      retq   

0000000000000010 <hello>:
  10:   8d 47 0a                lea    0xa(%rdi),%eax
  13:   c3                      retq
```

fun3 added 3 fun0 added 7, the call to fun0 was inlined and I end up from two files one external function one internal inlined, just add 10.

I used C here but llvm/clang like gnu thats just a front end, what happens in the middle as shown above with gnu should behave the same independent of C and C++ (as far as optimization doing automatic or suggested inlining).