# Understanding what the 'stack' is showing in gdb when going into a label

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, gdb

I have the following assembly:

```
_start:    
    mov $strings,   %rbx
    mov $1,         %r12d
  print_loop:
    mov %rbx,       %rdi
```

It is simple enough, but here is what it shows in `gdb` for each of these three lines/instructions:

1. `mov $strings, %rbx`

   ```
   0x00000000004000c4  ? mov    $0x6000ea,%rbx # memory address of 'strings'

   ─── Stack ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   [0] from 0x00000000004000c4 in _start
   ```
2. `mov $1, %r12d`

   ```
   0x00000000004000cb  ? mov    $0x1,%r12d

   ─── Stack ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   [0] from 0x00000000004000cb in _start
   ```
3. But then on the third instruction -- the first one after the label -- things look wonky:

   ```
   0x00000000004000d1  ? mov    %rbx,%rdi

   ─── Stack ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   [0] from 0x00000000004000d1 in print_loop
   [1] from 0x0000000000000001
   [2] from 0x00007fffffffe5aa
   [3] from 0x0000000000000000
   ```

What does that mean exactly, and why does it show things like that? It seems like the stack should still show one line:

```
[0] from 0x00000000004000d1 in print_loop
- or - 
[0] from 0x00000000004000d1 in _start
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does that mean exactly,

It means that GDB believes that you are executing inside `print_loop` function, and that it thinks this function was called from some code at address `0x1`, which was called from address `0x7fffffffe5aa`, etc.

> and why does it show things like that?

It is confused.

> It seems like the stack should still show one line:

Correct.

---

Now, your next question is probably "why does GDB get confused?".

The answer is somewhat complicated.

On platforms which do not use a dedicated frame pointer register, such as `x86_64`, there is no *general* way for GDB to unwind the stack, and it needs help from the compiler to do so. Compilers create "unwind tables", which GDB interprets to perform stack unwinding.

Since you are writing in assembly, and did not use `.cfi_...` directives, your code does not have any unwind descriptors.

In the absence of unwind descriptors, GDB can only guess, and here guesses incorrectly.

To fix this, you *can* provide unwind descriptors, something like this (untested):

```
_start:
    .cfi_startproc
    .cfi_undefined(rip)     # no unwinding past this function    
    mov $strings,   %rbx
    mov $1,         %r12d
  print_loop:
    mov %rbx,       %rdi
...
    .cfi_endproc
```

and that should unconfuse GDB. Documentation of various `.cfi` directives can be found [here](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/CFI-directives.html).

Comment: So does GDB special-case `_start` to not try to unwind the stack while executing inside it?  Because it knows that the stack contents will be `argc` and `argv[]`....

Comment: Is `.cfi` short for "Call Frame" ?Or what are those directives generally related to?

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 I believe `CFI` stands for "call frame info".

Comment: @samuelbrody1249: A quick google for `site:stackoverflow.com cfi directive` finds a bunch of stuff including [What are CFI directives in Gnu Assembler (GAS) used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2529185) which answers that question.  And see https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/CFI-directives.html.  In general, try googling your questions before asking other people to spend their time answering comments, especially broad questions.